# Is a $C^1$ differentiable function with non-singular differential always open?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $f:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R^2$ be differentiable in a neighborhood of $x_0$ with continuous partial derivatives. Then is $f$ necessarily an open map in some neighborhood of $x_0$?

It's true if $f$ is holomorphic but it seems to me that the only thing that should be needed is that the partial derivatives of $f$ be non-colinear (guaranteed for $f$ holomorphic since holomorphic maps are conformal).

Comment: The inverse function theorem shows that every point in the range has a neighbourhood also in the range.

Comment: @copper.hat So basically what I need is the surjectivity portion of the IFT?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. If $U$ is open and $y_0 \in f(U)$ then there is some neighbourhood of $y_0$ that lies in $f(U)$. This shows that $f(U)$ is open.

Comment: Your title is different from your question.